# Linking Shared library (which has dependency on other shared library) in CMake

Tags: cmake, caffe

I am trying to build an executable which links to a shared library (named 'caffe'). The shared library is dependent on another shared library (named 'cblas'). When I try to link to caffe in my CMake file it shows the following error:

> libcblas.so.3, needed by libcaffe.so, not found (try using -rpath or
>   -rpath-link)

I am using the following statements in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories(${BINARIES}/lib)
add_library(CAFFE_LIBRARY SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(CAFFE_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${BINARIES}/lib/libcaffe.so)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CAFFE_LIBRARY)
```

Both 'cblas' and 'caffe' libraries are present in `${BINARIES}/lib` folder.

Do I need to add cblas.so to `target_link_libraries` also? Also, i am not building caffe.so so building it via CMake and keeping it as a dependency is not an option

Is there any other feasible solution for the same problem where dependency tree of shared library needs to be resolved while linking?

Answer (score 1):

Browsing through the library's GitHub tree, it seems to me that it provides a package config file. Therefore, if you have installed it in the normal way, you should be able to find it as a package, instead of defining the imported target yourself:

```
find_package(Caffe)
include_directories(${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Caffe_DEFINITIONS})    # ex. -DCPU_ONLY

add_executable(caffeinated_application main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(caffeinated_application ${Caffe_LIBRARIES})
```

The example above comes from the [Caffe documentation](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1667) on the topic.

Comment: I have got a customized version of caffe.so . Hence building Caffe from source is not an option here.

Comment: @iotaSingh That's very relevant info that should have been in the question; please edit it in. Does the unmodified Caffe also depend on cblas? If so, its package config file should still be usable for you. If not, please clarify that in the question and I will expand the answer accordingly.